# Where can I find documentation for Crafter Profile and Crafter Social

Tags: crafter-cms

Where can I find documentation for Crafter Profile and Crafter Social for CMS version 2.5.x? I am looking at http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/developers/projects/profile/index.html but there is not much information there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find more documentation in the 3.0 version of the docs, and most of it is applicable to 2.5
Profile: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/projects/profile/index.html
Social: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/projects/social/index.html